# Derivation of flow equations in a digraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a digraph called `weightedG` and like to derive some relations between flows.

```
SeedRandom[9];
n = 5;
d = 0.3;
G = RandomGraph[{Round[n], Round[n*(n - 1)*d]}, DirectedEdges -> True];
A = {{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}, {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5}, {c1, c2, c3, c4, 
    c5}, {d1, d2, d3, d4, d5}, {e1, e2, e3, e4, e5}};
Ga = AdjacencyMatrix[G]*A;
sa = SparseArray[Ga];
weightedG = 
  Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"], 
   DirectedEdges -> True, VertexCapacity -> {i_ :> i}, 
   VertexSize -> .12, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"];
SetProperty[weightedG, 
 VertexLabels -> {i_ :> 
    Placed[PropertyValue[{weightedG, i}, VertexCapacity], Center]}]

deneme[g_, s_, t_] := Module[{eList, source, sink},
   eList = DeleteDuplicates[EdgeList@g];
   source = Cases[eList, DirectedEdge[s, _]];
   sink = Cases[eList, DirectedEdge[_, t]];
   Equal @@ {Simplify@
      Total[PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ source], 
     Simplify@Total[PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ sink]}];
```

The example digraph is:
[image]

```
deneme[weightedG, 3, 2]
```

yields:

```
Case 1:   c5 == d2 + e2
```

Another case:

```
deneme[weightedG, 1, 5]
```

yields

```
Case 2:   a4 == c5
```

and

```
Case 3:   deneme[weightedG, 1, 6]
```

yields

```
a4 == 0
```

because the digraph has only `5 vertices`. In some case, such equations as in `Case 3` may occur even when `vertex 6` is a vertex in the digraph.

In this `Module` I simply equalize the sum of the flow from `source=3` to the sum of the flow into `sink=2`. This is just an example, and one can play with alternative specifications.

My questions:

-- I like to formulate the `Module` in the following format:

```
 deneme=Module[(* the code *) ]&
```

and express `deneme` as a function of three variables: `deneme[weightedG, s, t]` as in the above examples.

-- For some vertices there may be no outgoing or incoming flows (as in `Case 3` above), and these cases should be deleted from the flow calculations without interrupting the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of the question:

```
deneme2 = Module[{eList, source, sink, g = #, s = #2, t = #3}, 
    eList = DeleteDuplicates[EdgeList@g];
    source = Cases[eList, DirectedEdge[s, _]];
    sink = Cases[eList, DirectedEdge[_, t]];
    Equal @@ {Simplify@Total[PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ source], 
      Simplify@Total[PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ sink]}] &;
```

Comment: I got an inspiration from @JMCompter-less's and your answers to other posts, and I solved the problem with `zero` issue but what is still hanging is  `True` or `False` cases.